# RecyclerView not filling in remaining space in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am learning android programming and working on a simple "post", "comment", "like" type of app. Never in a million years would I have thought the hardest part of building an android app would be trying to get the layout to work. I have all the info from the firebase database, that was easy, but trying to get the layout to look right is next to impossible. I even tried copy/paste from their quickstart apps for firebase, the one that does the database stuff. Still, it will not fill the area. The top section looks great, but I have a RecyclerView that is supposed to be repeating the comments for that post, it is repeating them, but it is only a tiny piece of the height of the page, as you can see in the screenshot. I have tried using ScrollView, NestedScrollView, putting the RecyclerView in a RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, nothing is working. Here is the xml for the view...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context="com.google.firebase.quickstart.auth.PostDetailActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/post_author_layout"
        layout="@layout/include_post_author"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/post_text_layout"
        layout="@layout/include_post_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/post_author_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/comment_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/post_text_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:weightSum="1.0">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/field_comment_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:hint="Write a comment..."/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_post_comment"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Post"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_comments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/comment_form"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_comment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Check out the screenshot, the comment section is so small, I took the screenshot in the middle of scrolling so you can see the top is in the right place, but the bottom is only a few pixels tall, it isn't going all the way to the bottom of the screen. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.
[image]

If I set the RecyclerView height to match_parent, I still only get one comment, since each comment is now the height of the parent. 
[image]

Comment: Remove `android:paddingBottom`?

Comment: Yep, remove the padding from the root layout

Comment: you mean on the RelativeLayout at the top? I tried that, it is only "5dp" so it doesn't really hurt much

Comment: can you include the layout of each row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since RecyclerView is a dynamic layout, you want to always fill the parent layout, not have it try to wrap its content.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_comments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/comment_form"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_comment" />
```

Comment: If I do that, it makes each comment the size of the remaining space. So there is only 1 comment shown, then you have to scroll down for more content. I will upload another pic to the OP to show with match_parent on the height of the RecyclerView.

Comment: Wait, you have a RecyclerView within each item of another RecyclerView?

Comment: If not, then something is wrong with your Post XML layout. The RecyclerView is now the correct size

Comment: You were correct. I had completely forgotten about the item_comment.xml file. It was a RelativeLayout with height of "match_parent". Can I ask one small favor please? Is there a way to make the text input and button be forced to the bottom, while allowing the other content to be scrollable?

Comment: RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout would anchor a view / viewgroup to the bottom... The other content would need to be in some scrollable view outside of view at the bottom